# Using client-side tools to store all the words in a dictionary

Tags: javascript, html

Right now I'm planning out how to make a page that uses my own implementation of a spellcheck algorithm. This of course requires reading from a dictionary. I downloaded a text file of all the words in the English dictionary and my plan was to store them in a JavaScript array on page load. I understand that the better way to do this would be to use server-side tools -- write a script that places all the words from the text file into rows of a table in my MySQL database, implement the part of my algorithm that checks for the word by using PHP connected to that table, etc. -- but right now I don't have a good enough knowledge of server-side tools and I'm just making this page for fun anyways. I was wondering:

(1) Is what I'm trying to do completely idiotic (even though I've checked and verified that a JavaScript array will be able to hold all the words)?

(2) Is there any type of fast-lookup structure I can use in JavaScript, or does the interpreter a.k.a. broswer implement large arrays as a hash table or binary tree anyways?

(3) When I put `<body onload="get_words()">`, I want `get_words()` to return a variable that is the array of my words or I somehow want the function to create a global variable. How do I do this? Do I have to put something like `<body onload="dict=get_words()">` ?????

Comment: Not sure I fully grasp the concept, but have you looked into using JSON?

Comment: And how big is this english dictionary that you plan to use?

Comment: Big. It's not just the most common words, but all words.

Comment: If I were you I would think in two directions. First - some kind of asynchronous calls to the server-side/database where you gonna store this dictionary, but the question here is the traffic that this gonna generate or second - use some type of caching strategy for the dictionary. I personally would try to avoid using AJAX because of the number of request that might be needed.